# Image in the top right corner of the table using css

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of some text, table and image. Is it possible to place image in the top right corner of the table? Also it is important to keep position of the divs as it is written (the next step would be to show image on table hover and I cannot achieve it when the image is before table).

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.div-img {
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
<div>Some more text</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1 </th>
      <th>Column 2 </th>
      <th>Column 3 </th>

    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Col_1_1</td>
      <td>Col_1_2</td>
      <td>Col_1_3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col_2_1</td>
      <td>Col_2_2</td>
      <td>Col_2_3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col_3_1</td>
      <td>Col_3_2</td>
      <td>Col_3_3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA90RVh0VGl0bGUAU2hvdztFeWU7SeMHJQAAAf1JREFUeF7tVjFrwkAYNf4JB2c3J+nf6OaYxdU/UVrsZAfByVGxQ8cgYhGSsXRoRHTIWi0VpJHSSrGg9Ou9cgeHueTSZCiFfPAg+L33vhdzuVyOiP4U/ytAFiAL0Gw2TxguGWyGZ4ZPgF/b6HFOToFEASDMM5gMcwaKiTnX5NMEgKjM4ArjXq9HjuPQYrGg7XZL+/0ewDV+Qw8cOQi05SQBIKgz7GDU7/dpOp1S3AIXGmi5Rz1uAAw2GFAEjEYjkuvlbUfW/SOdXT+QeeVQVEErfLinESdAS4g8zyO5vKdXatxM6PTiVoA0BQ85RCsqAIbXBHm1WgXuXAyXEaPgJYeoqQJgeJHhA6TZbHbsgb8dAwOIW/CEN59RVAXogDAYDFR6PPM0AQB4ixAdVYANmr7vq7RYcGkDwFsE2KgC+Giu12tNAD3AVRS8RQBfFaCNpmVZmkegB7iKgrcI0FYFKDC8gzAejyMWoR7gHhc84c1nFMJewyrDF4jL5VLzGqoBDrhywQue3Luq24ganIwtVbMRBYaDE9iWhR+8NTthMMRwOKTD4RC2FQO4xm/ynUMDbcRw/cfIFGui2+2S67oUs8CFRn7mZtLPcYnhDkYiiG3bYZ9j9OTBxLWltAcSgy/OCUxjYsI1RvIDiTpMheE84kiGXuU3R7LsVJwFyAJ8A1C9Ckk935p4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the position of a container element to `relative`, you can move an element whose position is `absolute` based on the bounds of the container element.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.div-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
<div>Some more text</div>
<div class="container">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <th>Column 1 </th>
        <th>Column 2 </th>
        <th>Column 3 </th>

      </thead>
      <tr>
          <td>Col_1_1</td>
          <td>Col_1_2</td>
          <td>Col_1_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Col_2_1</td>
          <td>Col_2_2</td>
          <td>Col_2_3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Col_3_1</td>
          <td>Col_3_2</td>
          <td>Col_3_3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="div-img">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
    </div>
</div>
```